# ¿Cómo pasar un atributo de instancia como argumento a un decorador?

Tags: python, atributos, decoradores

Sé que no se puede utilizar un atributo de instancia como argumento en un método  porque los parámetros de este se evalúan antes de que se cree la instancia. Pero me interesa hacer algo como lo siguiente.

```
class deco2:
    def __init__(self, activation, nombre):
        self.activation = activation
        self.nombre = nombre

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wraped(*args, **kwargs):
            print (f'{self.activation} {self.nombre}')
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wraped

class Base:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

    @deco2('update', self.nombre)
    def update(self, arg):
        print (f"{arg} desde método update")

b = Base('NombreInstancia')
b.update('prueba')
```

He indagado en el módulo ´´´inspect´´´ pero no he sido capaz de encontrar la forma de conocer el nombre de la instancia de un método. Otra cosa que sería interesante saber como se hace.
¿Que solución le daríais?

---

Siguiendo la recomendación de FJSevilla lo aplico de la siguiente forma. Pero me surge un nuevo problema...
Me doy cuenta de que no es necesario pasarle argumentos a la clase decoradora y obtengo la información que necesito desde la función decorada y la instancia. Pero ¿Es imprescindible que el decorador tenga unos paréntesis vacíos?

```
class Deco2:
    def __init__(self, deco_arg=None):
        self.deco_arg = deco_arg

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wraped(instance, *args, **kwargs):
            attr_val = instance.nombre
            func_name = func.__name__
            print (f'{func_name} {attr_val}')
            func(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        return wraped

class Base:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

    @Deco2()
    def update(self, arg):
        print (f"{arg} desde método update")

b = Base('NombreInstancia')
b.update('prueba')
```

Al quitarle los paréntesis veo que el funcionamiento de la clase decoradora cambia. **init** recibe como argumento la función a decorar y **call** los argumentos de la función. Intento acceder a la instancia de la clase Base pero lo que intento falla.
De momento estoy en el siguiente punto y no entiendo muy bien que está pasando.

```
class Deco2:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.f_name = func.__name__

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def wraped(instance, *args, **kwargs):
            attr_val = instance.valor
            print (f'{self.f_name} {attr_val}')
            self.func(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        return wraped

class Base:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

    @Deco2
    def update(self, arg):
        print (f"{arg} desde método update")

b = Base('Atributo b.valor')
b.update('prueba')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución más obvia sería en vez de pasar el atributo directamente al decorador (lo cual no es posible porque el atributo no existe hasta que se ejecuta el inicializador como comentas), interceptarlo en tiempo de ejecución (cuando se produce la llamada a `__call__`) a partir del método decorado, el cual recibe siempre como primer argumento la instancia de la clase a la que pertenece, con la cual podemos acceder al atributo de forma simple.

Para hacer el decorador más flexible, se le puede pasar el nombre del atributo como una cadena y usar `getatrr` para obtenerlo a partir de la instancia. Esto nos permite usar el decorador con cualquier atributo de instancia independientemente de su nombre.

Una posible implementación de la idea:

```
class Deco2:
    def __init__(self, activation, attr):
        self.activation = activation
        self._attr_name = attr

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wraped(instance, *args, **kwargs):
            attr_val = getattr(instance, self._attr_name)
            print (f'{self.activation} {attr_val}')
            func(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        return wraped

class Base:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

    @Deco2('update', "nombre")
    def update(self, arg):
        print (f"{arg} desde método update")

b = Base('NombreInstancia')
b.update('prueba')
```

**Salida:**

> update NombreInstancia
>   prueba desde método update

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas conocer el nombre de una instancia de modelo puedes usar `name = mymodel.__name__` o mas especifico `name = instancia.__name__` , despues puedes usar esta variable como desees